# composer cannot find pdo_mysql php extension

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When I tried to run PHP composer command : php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini ~/composer.phar

install, the composer returns the following message and I cannot run the laravel framework.

```
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library       
 '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so: undefined
 symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0

 Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                             
  Error Output: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library   
  '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0
```

I googled, and I tried run sudo apt-get install php5-mysql, it saids php5-mysql already the

newest. And I tried to run command sudo php5enmod pdo_mysql. But I run the php composer

again, same error happened. It seems php5 cannot find pdo_mysql. I believed it may caused by

PHP installation. I tried to remove the PHP5 mannually. So how can I make PHP find the

pdo_mysql again? Thanks

Comment: Which version of php exactly is it you are using?

Comment: Make sure it is uncommented in php.ini

Comment: I am using PHP 5.5.9

Comment: It can find `pdo_mysql`, but there is an error in that file